# How can I detect and filter "good morning images"?

Tags: python, flutter, dart, deep-learning

So I am making an app which can auto detect "Good Morning Images" and sort them in a gridview and provides a button on the app for the user to delete the Good Morning Image.

I need guidance to make this app

can anyone help me with this??

Video References or Any Github Repository

I have used chatgpt 3 but still it's not that good

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Till now I have tried this

https://chat.openai.com/share/41c8bfef-9b46-41f5-8e13-332790e15224

Comment: it would be helpful to users to post the code and show which part you are stuck on.

Comment: this requires deep learning. you should explain what "good morning messages" are. [this is apparently a local cultural phenomenon that has received global recognition as early as 2018](https://nypost.com/2018/01/25/good-morning-messages-in-india-are-clogging-up-the-internet/).